# What's the best way for add a wait time before every request?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

For example:

```
HttpClient hc =...
...
//need a wait time(Thread.sleep(xxx)) here before executing
hc.execute(post)
...
//need a wait time(Thread.sleep(xxx)) here before executing
hc.execute(get)
...
...
```

What's the best way to do it? Thanks a lot for any suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if you want at least a certain amount of time to wait. Thread.sleep is not guaranteed to sleep the time you provide as argument.
Also sleep can be interrupted, so you need to take this into account.

You can do something like this:

```
public static void waitAtLeast(long millis) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    while (true) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        long timeWaited = (now - startTime) / 1000000L;
        if (timeWaited > millis) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis - timeWaited);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```